# CSS doesn't load on the live server

Tags: css

As I put the CSS files on the public root folder of the live site, the CSS doesn't load on the live site.

Comment: What path to your CSS is being rendered in the HTML?

Comment: My staging server path is "http://www.viastarcenter.com.php56-33.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/assets/css/app.css"

Comment: On my local site, I usually put the assets folder on the root folder of the site.

Comment: What is your ``root`` folder? Typically that would be ``/home/user/public`` or ``public_html``.  The ``craft`` folder would live above that inside ``user``. So in your case, the assets folder should go into ``public``.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the path is not accurate.

If you're 100% sure that the path is correct, then check your file permissions. Small chance the permissions are locked down too tight.